# Dart - Replacing regex match in the middle of String

Tags: html, regex, string, flutter, dart

I'm trying to remove all links from a html string and to do so I'm using a regex to replace all `<a>` tags by `<p>`. The regex works fine when the tag is isolated, but in the middle of the string, it doesn't work.

```
String tag = '<a href=\"https://www.google.com/\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">word</a>';
String html = 'regex with a <a href=\"https://www.google.com/\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"noopener\">word</a> in the middle';

const regexString = r'^<a href=[a-zA-Z0-9_\W]([^>]*)';
final regex = RegExp(regexString);

html = html.replaceAll(regex, '<p').replaceAll('</a>', '</p>');
tag = tag.replaceAll(regex, '<p').replaceAll('</a>', '</p>');
  
print(tag); //<p>word</p>
print(html); //regex with a <a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank" rel="noopener">word</p> in the middle
```

I'm expecting the result of `print(html)` to be the same as `print(tag)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `regex` to this:

```
const regexString = r'<a href=[a-zA-Z0-9_\W]([^>]*)';
```

`^` at the start of your regex make it to check only start of string.

for replacing `<a>` with `" "` you can try this:

```
const regexString = r'<a href=[a-zA-Z0-9_\W]([^>]*)>';
```

Comment: It works, thank you! May I ask how do I add the ```>``` at the end of regex cause now I'm getting the string like this: 
>word and
regex with a >word in the middle

Comment: are you sure? I test that every thing works fine. what string are you using to get this result?

Comment: The same one in the question. But now i'm trying to replace the <a> tags by an empty char ('')

Comment: I get this when use the regex in my answer: `regex with a <p>word</p> in the middle`

Comment: I was using '<p' in replace because the > was coming from regex

Comment: Check out my last update.